# how to extend partition remotely for a virtual machine using powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, powershell-remoting

I have attempted to write a Powershell script to remotely extend a partition of a virtual machine. I have added 1gb to the existing C drive which would make it 81GB on the VDI but I deliberately did not extended it as I want to do it by this script.

Any ideas of what I am doing wrong as I would like to run it on a group machines which a list resides in the text file:

```
$servers = Get-Content 'C:\MININT\Computers.txt'
$GlobalResults = @()
$ConvertToGB = ( 1024 * 1024 * 1024 )
ForEach ($server in $servers)
{
    $disk = get-wmiobject win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $server -Filter "DeviceID='C:'" | Select-object size,Freespace    
$server + "," + ($disk.size / $ConvertToGB) + "," + ($disk.Freespace / $ConvertToGB)    
$MaxSize =  (Get-PartitionSupportedSize -DriveLetter c).sizeMax
    Resize-Partition -DriveLetter c -Size $MaxSize
}
```

Any assist would be greatly appreciated as I am a beginner on this.

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can perform remote actions with `invoke-command` (http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_invoke.htm) where you have to prepend "using:" when you want to use local variables on that remote machine (and calculate to GB by simply "dividing to GB")

as I cannot test right now - the following is how it "should work" (as in: not tested but I hope you get the idea)

```
$servers = Get-Content 'C:\MININT\Computers.txt'
ForEach ($server in $servers)
{      
    $MaxSize = (invoke-command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock { Get-PartitionSupportedSize -DriveLetter c }).sizeMax
    invoke-command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock {Resize-Partition -DriveLetter c -Size $using:MaxSize}
}
```

Comment: Hi Really appreciate the assist but unfortunately did not work:

Comment: A Using variable cannot be retrieved. A Using variable can be used only with Invoke-Command, Start-Job, or InlineScript in the script workflow. When it is used with Invoke-Command, the 
Using variable is valid only if the script block is invoked on a remote computer.
At C:\SUPPORT\increase disk v2.ps1:5 char:5
+     $MaxSize = (invoke-command -ComputerName $using:vdi -ScriptBlock  ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UsingWithoutInvokeCommand

Comment: I manage to get rid of one error by removing $using:server and changing it to $server. Unfortunately have a different issue now:

Comment: [PC-1-test] Connecting to remote server PC-1-test failed with the following error message : The client cannot connect to the destination specified in the request. Verify that 
the service on the destination is running and is accepting requests. Consult the logs and documentation for the WS-Management service running on the destination, most commonly IIS or WinRM. 
If the destination is the WinRM service, run the following command on the destination to analyze and configure the WinRM service: "winrm quickconfig". For more information, see the

Comment: You have to enable PSRemoting on the target. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/enable-psremoting?view=powershell-5.1 . GPO can also be used to start the WinRM service, configure PSRemoting with trustedhosts and enabling the firewall rules

Comment: Try Enable-PsRemoting to enable remoting and the winrm service.

Answer (score 0):

It can all be done on the remote machine:

```
$Svr = Get-Content 'C:\MININT\Computers.txt'

$ScriptBlock = {
$MaxSize = (Get-PartitionSupportedSize -DriveLetter C).Sizemax

Resize-Partition -DriveLetter C -Size $MaxSize
}

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Svr -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock
```